# Dependent dropdown list using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a dropdown list to select State which is dependent on the another dropdown list Country.

Based on the Country selected from the first list, the second dropdown list should display corresponding states of the country.

For both the dropdown list I need to fetch values from the SQL server database.

Here is the code am trying:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js">                    </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){


           $("#country").change(function(){
                 var country=$("#country").val();
                 $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"getcity.php",
                    data:"country="+country,
                    success:function(data){
                          $("#city").html(data);
                    }
                 });
           });
       });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    Country :
    <select name="country" id="country">
      <option>-select your country-</option>

    <?php 

    include "dbconfig.php"; 

    $sql = "SELECT [CountryId],[Country] from Country order by [Country]";
    $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
    while($country = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<option value = $country[CountryId]>$country[Country]</option>";

    } ?>
    </select>


    City :
    <select name="city" id="city">
        <option>-select your city-</option>
     </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Below is the getcity.php code :

```
   <?php

      include "dbconfig.php";

      $country=$_POST["country"];

     $sql= "select [StateID],[State] from State where CountryId='$country'";
     $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
     while($city=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo"<option value='$city[StateID]'>$city[State]</option>";
     }

     ?>
```

I made database connection code in the file dbconnection.php and it is working fine, successfully connected with the database.

When I run this code I am not able to get the dropdown list of states after selecting the country. The code doesn't return any error but dropdown list of state not appear after selecting the country.

Comment: Have you tried to run the getcity.php independently to see if it yields the desired result?

Comment: Have a look at your browser network tab when the AJAX request fires, to check it is being made, and to see what the reply is. Check your JavaScript console too, for errors. Don't go live yet - you have a SQL injection vuln here.

Comment: @halfer: Yes executed getcity.php independently,i am getting the desired result. But when i am selecting country ID from dropdown it's not working.

Comment: Hi. Please don't revert edits from experienced editors here until you are familiar with the formatting guidelines. Titles use sentence case not title case, all "thanks in advance" are trimmed out, and correct case (including the personal pronoun "I") is observed.

Comment: Have you tried your browser's network monitor?

Comment: @halfer: No, am not getting what is it?

Comment: Here is [the monitor for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor). All modern browsers have them, either natively or as a plugin.